# I have the same game purchased both on Uplay and Steam. How do I launch the steam version of the game?

Tags: steam, ubisoft-connect, ghost-recon-future-soldier

- I brought Ghost Recon Future Solider on Uplay long time ago
- I also brought the same game on Steam recently
- When I go to Library on Steam and download the game and launch it, it again downloads the game on Uplay
- How do I play the Steam version of my game on Uplay
- In my case, only one steam and one Uplay account in total

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What happens if I buy a game I own on Uplay, on Steam?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/148969/what-happens-if-i-buy-a-game-i-own-on-uplay-on-steam)

Comment: @Mixxiphoid i saw that before posting this question, it doesnt :( i cannot see the steam version of my game on uplay at all, my steam version was deluxe edition whereas the uplay one was regular, i am not seeing the extra goody goodies of the deluxe version in my game

Comment: i wanted to add that i have fixed this issue, i contacted support and they moved my uplay version of the game to another account